# How do I develop for features that require Facebook Graph API permissions that are disabled during development?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

> While creating a new web application that uses the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/)
>   some features are blocked during development and only enabled after
>   [App Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/).
>
> App Review requires the working end-product and screen-cast to be reviewed.

**How can these disabled features be “tested” and developed?**

*It sound’s like a catch-22 situation to me - a vicious cycle. The app required review to enable features, yet needs those features to be developed.*

---

Specifically, I need the [`Page Public Content Access` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/) to access public pages posts.

> *e.g.* Use [this request](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=jakepaul%2Ffeed%3Ffields%3Dicon%2Cfull_picture%2Ccreated_time%2Cpicture%2Cmessage%2Ctype%26limit%3D100&version=v3.1) to access a public page

Comment: Use a page you have admin access to and a page token to request the data you need, build your functionality and make the screencast based on that. Switch that part out for a user or app access token later, when you got PPCA approved.

Comment: I understand - so there is no way to do this and receive data from a/any real existing page?

Comment: You can use any real page you have admin access to; you just need to use a page token or page admin user token, because only then the API knows that you have access, and this is _not_ anonymous access to a public page.